# Import RxAndroid to Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, rx-java

I am trying to import [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) to Android Studio 1.0.2. As soon as I import project from Gradle using default gradle wrapper, I face with following error:

[image]

Is there anyone who know the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I just put `compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'` in the gradle `dependencies` and it works fine.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
}
```

your build.gradle file under the app should be some like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.map_ex"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
}
```

and then you can use classes from RxAndroid

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid, could you check the link and tell me which file? I can't file any file with following dependencies!!

Comment: just in the [Readme.md](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/blob/0.x/README.md) has the for `Gradle`: compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'

Comment: I mean you need to put 'compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'' in your app 's 'build.gradle ' file, see edit

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudio is a special version of IntelliJ IDEA tailored to work with`android-gradle-plugin`. AndroidStudio is supposed to be used for building android apps and android libraries.

RxAndroid is java library project built with Nebula's `gradle-rxjava-project-plugin` which is not compatible with `android-gradle-plugin`. Therefore can't be opened at AndroidStudio. You can use IntelliJ for now.

See for reference: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/pull/81 , https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/74